# path.resolve() was not pointing the templates/blogpost.js in gatsby application

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm developing very basic blog application that display blog posts from markdown files. When i click each post, it will open on the new route with dynamically create page with createPages functionality. The problem is When i pointing the templates/blogpost.js in the gatsby-node.js.

It is showing like this.

Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page with a component that doesn't exist.

Error :

```
The path to the missing component is "C:\Users\viper\Desktop\react\gatsby\portfolio\imlohith\src\templates\blog.js"

The page object passed to createPage:
{
    "path": "/post-four",
    "component": "C:\\Users\\viper\\Desktop\\react\\gatsby\\portfolio\\imlohith\\src\\templates\\blog.js"
}
```

```
const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blog.js`)
  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            html
            id
            frontmatter {
              path
              title
              date
              author
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(res => {
    if (res.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(res.errors)
    }

    res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.frontmatter.path,
        component: postTemplate,
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Gatsby-congig.js file

```
const config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: config.pathPrefix,
  siteMetadata: {
    title: config.siteTitle,
    description: "This is awesome site awesome awesome"
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-catch-links',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    { 
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: config.manifestName,
        short_name: config.manifestShortName,
        start_url: config.pathPrefix || config.manifestStartUrl,
        background_color: config.manifestBackgroundColor,
        theme_color: config.manifestThemeColor,
        display: config.manifestDisplay,
        icon: config.manifestIcon, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
  ],
};
```

Comment: The title of your post says the filename is "blogpost.js" but in your resolve() expression, it's "src/templates/blog.js", are you sure you passed the correct filename?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed the problem. Reason im getting the error because , I put templates folder from outside of source directory and call with src/templates/blogpost.js. . That the problem i faced. thank you